# Installing the Python3 bindings for libtorrent on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, libtorrent

I'm trying to install libtorrent for Python3. It's a wrapper for a C++ library. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-libtorrent

$ sudo apt-get install python3-libtorrent

$ sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev

$ sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev
```

The [PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libtorrent/1.1.0) doesn't have a download link, and as a result it doesn't seem to be installable via pip. Interestingly, it seems to work in Python2, but unfortunately, the rest of the project is in Python3.

Answer (score -1):

On Non-Windows System:

The setup.py is generated by running `./configure --enable-python-binding`.

Choose the **Python version** you want to install with.

To build the Python bindings do:

Run:

```
python setup.py build
```

As root, run:

```
python setup.py install
```

For detailed Information see: http://www.libtorrent.org/python_binding.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'` in python3 and now I get `ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libtorrent.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10libtorrent20generate_fingerprintENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiiii` in python2. The only thing I can think of is that `setup.py` is written in python2.7, so I had to use that rather than python3. Maybe doing that means it tried to intall it for python2 rather than 3.